# Why would this Access 2010 report have extra white space at the bottom when using a criteria?

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I've developed an Access 2010 report that shows sets of deadlines by staff member.  The only displayed part of the form is the Group Header.  Page Header, Detail, and Page Footer are all set to visible = no, Height = 0, and Detail is set to Can Shrink = Yes.

When I open the report without filtering for an individual staff member, it shows a group for each staff member as intended, with no white space at the end.  However, when I filter for a specific staff member (which is how the report will usually be used), there is white space below the report contents.  Resizing the window does not work; the report reverts to the same size every time I open it.  I have an Event set for On Close that opens a different form, but no other Events.

[Edit to add] I do not have a background image set

Report screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a background image set? This appears to be a background issue perhaps?

Comment: @random_answer_guy I do not have a background image set.  Would a background image be the possible problem or a possible solution?

Comment: I find Reports very finicky - and often dependent more on the Printer and its settings. What does your screenshot show - is this with filtering?

Comment: @dbmitch yes, this is with the filtering